# How can I get the Node.js source code of a WebSite?

Tags: node.js

How can I get the node.js runTime source code of a webSite?

(Please don't misunderstand as "How can I get the source code of a webSite using node.js?")

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "Node.js source code of a website"?  Websites don't need to run Node.js.  Node.js applications don't need to have anything to do with websites.  What exactly are you trying to do?  If you're trying to get server-side code of any kind that isn't exposed to the client, you can't....

Comment: Unless the site's creators have chosen to publish it, you generally can't access the server-side code of a web site/app, Node.js or otherwise.

Comment: The best answer you can get, given how vague the question is

Comment: "Node.js source code of a website"  means the source code of a webSite witch is developed with Node.js.

Comment: Let's happy with only code from yourself. Don't become a thief :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless the owners of a server have purposely or accidentally left them open for public access or unless they have purposely published their code, you cannot access server-side code in the same way that you can access client-side Javascript code.

Servers are typically secure and the server-side code runs inside that security and you cannot access it.

FYI, it doesn't matter whether it's node.js or some other environment.  Server-side code is not typically publicly accessible.

You can make requests to the server (just like the browser does) and if the site's pages use Javascript to make ajax calls back to the site's server, then you can also typically make those Ajax calls from your own client.  But, this is accessible at the http request level only, not at the source code level.